# Passing argument to a constructor and using it only in some class methods

Tags: php, controller, constructor

I've created some controller for handling clicked links statistics. Does this class meet Single Responsibility Principle?

```
class StatisticsController
{
    protected $statisticsQuery;

    public function __construct(StatisticsQuery $statisticsQuery)
    {
        $this->statisticsQuery = $statisticsQuery;
    }

    public function recordClickedLink(array $request)
    {
        (...)
        if ($this->canRecordClick()) {
            // record clicked link
        }
        (...)
    }

    public function getStatistics(array $request)
    {
        (...)
        $someRequestParam = $request['id'];
        $statistics = $this->statisticsQuery->get($someRequestParam);
        (...)
    }

    protected function canRecordClick()
    {
        // returns true of false
    }
}
```

If has two public methods. The first is responsible for saving clicked link to a database by delegating it to a model class. The second public method is responsible for getting statistics and it is the only method which use `$statisticsQuery` object passed to a class' constructor. Is it OK that `recordClickedLink` method doesn't need constructor's argument?

I wonder also if it is OK that my class contain `canRecordClick` method with logic for checking if link click can be saved during particular request.

If this class doesn't meet SRP, how can I refactor it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see in the code example you've provided, it seems that the `getStatistics` and `recordClickedLink` methods are independent of each other. So it seems intuitive to have in this case two controllers: a `StatisticsController` and a something like a `RecordController` where the two methods `recordClickedLink` and `canRecordClick` live. In that way the `StatisticsController` is responsible for statisics and the `RecordController` for the record.

It is ok that the class contains `canRecordClick`, but `protected` means that any class extending the `StatisticsController` will be able to call this method too. If it will only be used in the `StatisticsController`, `private` would be better.

Comment: Do you think that constructor's argument can be considered when telling if this class applies SRP? I wonder if argument or arguments passed to constructor should be obligatorily used by all class' public methods.

Comment: @SzymonCzembor The argument of a constructor or properties of a class can give a good indication but it is not a strict rule that each method should use all the properties of a class (there are probably some who disagree). Determining what falls under a single responsibility of a class can sometimes be difficult to determine and sometimes you also have to take into consideration how easy some code is to understand vs adding a new class.

Comment: And what do you think about this? If I have two classes (StatisticsController and RecordController) and then I need to change the way I record a link click (for example altering database table) in RecordController then I have to change also StatisticsController because data for calculating statistics come from the altered place. Does it imply that this two methods should be in one class, doesn't it?

Comment: If that is the case you could extract the code which alters and reads from the database to a separate repository class and pass that repository to both the StatisticsController and RecordController. Then when you change the way you record a link you only have to change the repository.